# Mongoose query: Match number partially

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am moving a client-side search to my node.js server. I am doing something like this:

```
{
          $or: [
            {name: new RegExp(textQuery, "i")},
            {age: new RegExp(textQuery, "i")},
            {street: new RegExp(textQuery, "i")}
          ]
        }
```

In the client app everything was just a string. Here my problem is that "age" is a Number field, so I obviously get a casting error.

How can I match objects where the age number matches the string query partially?

Comment: what's the content of your text query?

Comment: Why you want to match age partially?

Comment: You should use exact number or range of numbers for age not a string regex

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I know what I am doing :) Exact match is dumb as it is - as I said - a client search which also highlights the matches in the objects, so I want "2" to match "27".

It's display as <match>2</match>7 in the UI. The question is how can I do this in mongoose

Comment: You'd have to use a (slow) `$where` query that does its own conversion and custom matching for that